# UWP - Incorrect behaviour when Trial Expired

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, trial

According to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt219685.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) when trial is expired and user opens the app, a message would be shown.  But my app closes after showing splash screen without any message in this case.

There is [the same question on the Microsoft's forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/8a907bac-0a3f-4f5d-b81e-658c14413383/uwptrial-experience-incorrect-behaviour-when-trial-expired?forum=wpdevelop), but I can't write anything there (it returns me `unexpected error` when I try to submit my question) and there is no answer.

I get the following line in my event log:

> App failed with error: No applicable app licenses found. See the Microsoft-Windows-Twin/Operational log for additional information.

Additional information:

> ```
> < Data Name="ErrorCode" >-1058406399< /Data >
> ```

Comment: what is you version of Windows?

Comment: Hi Tuấn Trần.
Thanks for you answer. This problem is reproduced for windows 10 only - trial period is work correctly on Windows8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Microsoft's bug and they promise to fix it. You can get more details [on the msdn-forum.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/2781f0f4-7377-4734-8864-7563a42576d5/uwp-incorrect-behaviour-when-trial-expired?forum=wpdevelop#21df6a08-dee4-447d-bf70-25e7508e7377)